# How to get environment variable in 64 bit Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, win64

Is there any way to retrieve the environment variable in 64 bit machine.
I already have %abc% which returns me variable in 32 bit machine, but doesn't work in 64 bit.

My Mistake:
How can I get through command line not through programming language?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable in 64 bits"?

Comment: What flavour of Windows do you have?

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell you'll get environment variables with

```
$Env:abc
```

This is independent of bit-ness.

In `cmd` you can get environment variables with

```
%abc%
```

this is also independent of bit-ness, so it would be nice if you'd elaborate what exactly you tried and where it failed and in what way.

Answer (score 0):

Try System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("abc")